# Users who edit their questions to be unintelligible after receiving an answer.

Tags: discussion, vandalism

Consider [this thread](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2054548/delete-topic-thread-pls), in which the user asked a question, received an answer, and then asked others to delete the question after receiving help. I have never seen this before, and I am not sure what the proper behavior is in this situation. Note that this is different from historical questions on meta such as [this situation](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/8528/why-do-some-users-delete-their-questions-after-receiving-an-answer) in which users would simply delete the question. I have never deleted a question I have asked, and am not knowledgeable of exactly which privileges are earned when, but I suppose it is possible this user is simply unable to delete their question, but either way it would still be problematic, as the previous discussion has shown. Note that in the second linked thread, Asaf proposes as a counter-measure to vote early and often for answers. In this case, this solution won't work, as the question has not been deleted but just vandalized.

So what should I do in this situation? Is it possible to 'roll back' a thread? I feel like it is counter to this site's purpose to vandalize one's question in this way, probably to avoid being incriminated for cheating in some sense.

Comment: "Is it possible to 'roll back' a thread?" Yes, there is a dedicated feature for this. Go to the revision history (link in the middle of the post, present [only] if there actually is an earlier revision). Scroll to the version to which you want to roll back, and click the link with that name in the header of that revision (to avoid confusion, let me add that for obvious reasons it is not present for the latest version).

Comment: See the revision of the example you mention for an example where it was done http://math.stackexchange.com/posts/2054548/revisions

Comment: This has happened to me with an answer I posted.  The answer was accepted, but the OP vandalized his question afterwards.  It wasn't until the teacher of his class commented on the OP that I found out I had answered homework for them.  Definitely on the list of Top 3 frustrations of ME.

Comment: @floorcat: You'll never get that problem if you don't answer questions without context. However, that causes a new frustration, when you see other people give full answers to those same questions...

Comment: Therein lies the rub, this site operates solely on privileges earned through reputation.  The best gains in reputation are answers, not questions.  Given that the question itself isn't even really a focus of the site, but that it gets answered well, you might as well be saying every question without context be put on hold to prevent users from cheating on their homework.

Answer (score 34):

The proper behavior is to roll-back the question and flag the destruction for moderator attention. You are correct --- it is against the site's purpose to vandalize questions in this way.